# How can I iterate over multiple arrays and add an exception after every nth iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops

This should be fairly simple and I know how to increase a counter in an iteration and how to nest loops - but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

How can I count how often an iteration has run and inject additional code every time it ran X times?

I tried using each_slice, but this is looking at the content of the array itself instead of the number of arrays.

Here's my sample code:

```
<% @organization.users.each do |user| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', organization_user_path(@organization, user.id) %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', '#' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

ideally I would run the loop 4 times and after the 4th time a new row would be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each_with_index` and use index to know the number of times the loop has run

```
<% @organization.users.each_with_index do |user, i| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', organization_user_path(@organization, user.id) %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', '#' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%if (i+1)%4 == 0 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```